# chart.js: How do I make the radar chart axis labels bigger?

Tags: chart.js

I would like a larger font size for the labels on the axis on my chart.js radar chart. See the red arrows on the image below:
[image: chart.js]

I have tried different variations of fontSize in the options section but with absolutely no success.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in the documentation: 
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#scale-title-configuration

e.g.:

```
options: options = {
        scale: {
            pointLabels: {
                fontSize: 24
            }
       }
}
```

Comment: Works in old version 2.7.1  to.